# Mark a question as "unanswerable"

Tags: feature-request, questions, accepted-answer, tags

StackOverflow has several subjective/poll questions that do not have an answer (by definition), I wish there was a way to let SO (and other community users) understand that there is no right answer to the question?

Comment: If the reason you're asking for this is the recently added "accept rate" feature: Community wiki questions don't count towards this ratio, and the questions you're talking about should be CW by definition.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

99% of the time, if you have a question that doesn't have a "correct" answer possible on it, then at the most you should be making it Community Wiki, and more likely you shouldn't be posting it at all.

Answer (score 4):

Since CW questions do not affect reputation and has no negative effect on anyone directly, even when accepting an answer I don't see an issue with the problem. I see no need to define this even further as it is covered fairly well in the FAQ already.

Also as [balpha](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115866/balpha) already pointed out, it does not affect the acceptance rate.